# Maria DB Update and replace

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm getting error message when run this:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_text
SET value = REPLACE (value, 'xxxxx') 
WHERE value LIKE 'yyyyy';
```

Error:   `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1`

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `Replace` needs 3 parameter and you have only 2 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 9):

I obtained the same error with the expression:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_tex
     SET value = REPLACE (value, 'yyyyy', 'xxxxx')
     WHERE value LIKE '%yyyyy%';
```

The solution was using alias:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_tex c
     SET c.value = REPLACE (c.value, 'yyyyy', 'xxxxx')
     WHERE c.value LIKE '%yyyyy%';
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace` is wrong. Here is correct way:

```
MariaDB [maison]> select replace('aaaaaa', 'a', 'b');
+-----------------------------+
| replace('aaaaaa', 'a', 'b') |
+-----------------------------+
| bbbbbb                      |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Your query must be something like:

```
UPDATE
   catalog_product_entity_text 
SET 
   value = REPLACE (value, 'xxxxx', 'zzzzz')
WHERE
   value LIKE 'yyyyy';
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace takes three arguments, not two.  Presumably, you want:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_tex
     SET value = REPLACE (value, 'yyyyy', 'xxxxx')
     WHERE value LIKE '%yyyyy%';
```

Also note the use of wildcards in the `LIKE` pattern.